# building websites with drupal

Tags: drupal, web

How can  I build a regular website using drupal? which module should I use for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular website" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how "regular" your "regular" website is, you might consider another platform.

All of Drupal's complexity and versatility, along with the time you spent learning them, would go to waste if you're just displaying a dozen or so static pages.

Is this is the case, Wordpress or Joomla might be better starting points.

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty generic question. You should check out http://drupal.org/start and work through their *Getting Started* documentation and tutorials. After that, you should have an easier time here or on their forums getting more specific information.

Answer (score 2):

According to Drupal founder [Dries Buytaert](https://dri.es/drupal-is-for-ambitious-digital-experiences), Drupal is not for building regular websites but for building "ambitious digital experiences".

*'Because Drupal evolved from a simple tool for hobbyists to a more powerful digital experience platform, many people believe that Drupal is now "for the enterprise". While I agree that Drupal is a great fit for the enterprise, I personally never loved that categorization. It's not just large organizations that use Drupal. Individuals, small startups, universities, museums and non-profits can be equally ambitious in what they'd like to accomplish and Drupal can be an incredible solution for them. Rather than using "for the enterprise", I thought "for ambitious digital experiences" was a good phrase to describe what people can build using Drupal. I say "digital experiences" because I don't want to confine this definition to traditional browser-based websites.'*

At the 2017 DrupalCon Vienna, Buytaert [stated](https://hostadvice.com/blog/drupalcon-vienna-2017-driesnote-state-of-drupal-address/): *"Drupal is no longer for simple sites, but for sites with medium to high richness."* Basically there are easier solutions for regular websites than maintaining Drupal securely in production on a web server.